# If second = 1, stop countdown for 3 seconds, the go to second = 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, countdown

I have a countdown for an auction website. At the end of the auction I want to display "going once". "going twice" and "final call" like real auction. This code displays "going once" at second = 3, "going twice at second = 2, and "final call' at second = 1.

```
if(hours == "00" && minutes == "00")
            {

                if(seconds < 50) { 

                        var color = thisDiv.css("background-color");
                        thisDiv.animate({color:"red"}, 'fast');
                        thisDiv.animate({color: "black"},'fast') ; 

                        }   

                        if(seconds == 3)
                        {
                            $(this).html("Going once!");    
                        }

                        if(seconds == 2)
                        {
                            $(this).html("Going twice!");   
                        }
                        if(seconds == 1)
                        {
                            $(this).html("Final call!");    
                        }

                        if(seconds == 0)
                        {
                            //$('.auction-current-time').countdown('destroy');
                            //$('.auction-current-time2').html("Auction Ended");
                            $(this).html("GONE!");
                            $(".mm_bid_mm").hide();
                             //alert("asd");    
                        }
            }
```

I would like to change this code to display "going once", "going twice" and "final call" only before second = 0, each should be displayed 1s.

I have no idea how to do this.

Thank you very much for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Is this just for effect or the user could interfere at the last moment and top the last bid to reset the timeout?

Comment: What does your code currently do? It sounds like you need to run a method every second? Have you tried `setInterval` or `setTimeout`?

Comment: Unless this function code is being called every second. It probably  wont do anything right now. Provide the full function. Where are `hours` `minutes` and `seconds` being initialized and to what? Also, there is nothing that increments or decrements `seconds`

Answer (score 0):

I have made a quick mock up of a count down clock, using roughly what you have here: http://jsfiddle.net/uqxn2jhr/

```
var countDownClock = function (hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var clock = $('[data-countdown="clock"]');
    var time = $('[data-countdown="time"]');
    var quick = $('[data-countdown="quick"]');

    time.html(
    ((hours < 10) ? '0' : '') + hours + ':' + ((minutes < 10) ? '0' : '') + minutes + ':' + ((seconds < 10) ? '0' : '') + seconds);

    if (hours === 0 && minutes === 0) {
        if (seconds == 3) {
            quick.html("Going once!");
        }

        if (seconds == 2) {
            quick.html("Going twice!");
        }
        if (seconds == 1) {
            quick.html("Final call!");
        }

        if (seconds == 0) {
            //$('.auction-current-time').countdown('destroy');
            //$('.auction-current-time2').html("Auction Ended");
            quick.html("GONE!");
            //$(".mm_bid_mm").hide();
            //alert("asd");    
        }
    }
}

var beginCountDown = function (hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var countDown = setInterval(function () {
        seconds = seconds - 1;
        console.log(seconds);
        if (seconds < 0 && (minutes > 0 || hours > 0)) {
            //reset seconds and reduce hours/minutes
        }

        if (seconds >= 0) {
            countDownClock(hours, minutes, seconds);
        } else {
            clearInterval(countDown);
            countDown = null;
        }
    }, 1000);
};
beginCountDown(0, 0, 10);
```

Does that help with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for your answers, I would like something more like this:

```
if(seconds == 4)
                    {
                        //$(this).html("Going once!");  
                    }
                    if(seconds == 3)
                    {
                        //$(this).html("Going twice!"); 
                    }

                    if(seconds == 2)
                    {
                        //$(this).html("Final call!");  
                    }
                    if(seconds == 1)
                    {
                        $('#box1').delay(1800).show('slow').promise()
                    .then(function(){ return $('#box2').delay(1800).show('slow').promise(); }).then(function(){ return $('#box2').delay(1800).hide('slow').promise(); }).then(function(){
return $('#box3').delay(1800).show('slow').promise(); }).then(function(){
return $('#box3').delay(1800).hide('slow').promise(); });
                    }
                    if(seconds == 0)
                    {
                    $(this).html("Bidding ended!");
                    }
```

I would like to add 1s when I display #box1, then 1s when I display #box2 etc. I am not sure if it's possible… thanks

I use query.countdown.js (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)